# No route specified for message

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, cqrs, event-sourcing

am following Mark Nihof (Fohjin) architecture for develop a cqrs based ecommerce application. My development framework is Asp.net MVC5. Reporting side work fine but when i try to execute command by browsing **localhost:63738/api/Security/Signup** it shows me following exception
No route specified for message 'RavenProject.Commands.CreateUserCommand'

My message router class is as follows:

```
public class MessageRouter : IRouteMessages
    {
        private readonly IDictionary<Type, ICollection<Action<object>>> _routes;

        public MessageRouter()
        {
            _routes = new Dictionary<Type, ICollection<Action<object>>>();
        }

        public void Register<TMessage>(Action<TMessage> route) where TMessage : class
        {
            var routingKey = typeof(TMessage);
            ICollection<Action<object>> routes;

            if (!_routes.TryGetValue(routingKey, out routes))
                _routes[routingKey] = routes = new LinkedList<Action<object>>();

            routes.Add(message => route(message as TMessage));
        }

        public void Route(object message)
        {
            ICollection<Action<object>> routes;

            if (!_routes.TryGetValue(message.GetType(), out routes))
                throw new RouteNotRegisteredException(message.GetType());

            foreach (var route in routes)
                route(message);
        }
    }
```

and my route register class is as follows:

```
public class RegisterCommandHandlersInMessageRouter
    {
        private static MethodInfo _createPublishActionWrappedInTransactionMethod;
        private static MethodInfo _registerMethod;

        public static void BootStrap()
        {
            new RegisterCommandHandlersInMessageRouter().RegisterRoutes(ObjectFactory.GetInstance<IRouteMessages>() as MessageRouter);
        }

        public void RegisterRoutes(MessageRouter messageRouter)
        {
            _createPublishActionWrappedInTransactionMethod = GetType().GetMethod("CreatePublishActionWrappedInTransaction");
            _registerMethod = messageRouter.GetType().GetMethod("Register");

            var commands = CommandHandlerFactory.GetCommands();
            var commandHandlers = CommandHandlerFactory.GetCommandHandlers();

            foreach (var command in commands)
            {
                IList<Type> commandHandlerTypes;
                if (!commandHandlers.TryGetValue(command, out commandHandlerTypes))
                    throw new Exception(string.Format("No command handlers found for event '{0}'", command.FullName));

                foreach (var commandHandler in commandHandlerTypes)
                {
                    var injectedCommandHandler = GetCorrectlyInjectedCommandHandler(commandHandler);
                    var action = CreateTheProperAction(command, injectedCommandHandler);
                    RegisterTheCreatedActionWithTheMessageRouter(messageRouter, command, action);
                }
            }
        }

        private static object GetCorrectlyInjectedCommandHandler(Type commandHandler)
        {
            return ObjectFactory.GetInstance(commandHandler);
        }

        private static void RegisterTheCreatedActionWithTheMessageRouter(MessageRouter messageRouter, Type commandType, object action)
        {
            _registerMethod.MakeGenericMethod(commandType).Invoke(messageRouter, new[] { action });
        }

        private object CreateTheProperAction(Type commandType, object commandHandler)
        {
            return _createPublishActionWrappedInTransactionMethod.MakeGenericMethod(commandType, commandHandler.GetType()).Invoke(this, new[] { commandHandler });
        }

        public Action<TCommand> CreatePublishActionWrappedInTransaction<TCommand, TCommandHandler>(TCommandHandler commandHandler)
            where TCommand : class
            where TCommandHandler : ICommandHandler<TCommand>
        {
            //return command => ObjectFactory.GetInstance<TransactionHandler<TCommand, TCommandHandler>>().Execute(command, commandHandler);
            return command => ObjectFactory.GetInstance<ICommandHandler<TCommand>>().Execute(command);
        }
    }
```

Where is my mistake yet i failed to identify.

Note: The method that I call from browser will actually a HTTP POST method but for checking purpose I used HTTP GET.

My Route Register class properly register all routes during bootstrap the application.

One can also check whole my work from following link
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1rU7HOTfLweZjFuZlF3M0Z2M28/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

You will still have to define the routes. See for example [here](https://github.com/MarkNijhof/Fohjin/blob/master/Fohjin.DDD.Example/Test.Fohjin.DDD/Bus/Command_bus.cs).

```
_handler = new FirstTestCommandHandler();
var messageRouter = new MessageRouter();
messageRouter.Register<TestCommand>(x => _handler.Execute(x));
DoNotMock.Add(typeof (IRouteMessages), messageRouter);
```